# React.js onclick handler not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using react.js as the templating library in my node.js application . I am using jsx syntax for my react components. I have a route like /entities which renders the entities.jsx file (it is a view) . I have the following code in my entities.jsx file. I am trying to call the onclickhandler in my code and its not working.I am not rendering it explicitly using React.render but the component is showing in the browser when I hit localhost:/entities but the onclick handler isnt firing.

```
  var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    alertMessage: function() {
       alert(this.props.name);                             
   },
    render: function () {
      return (
       <div onClick={this.alertMessage}>
        Hello {this.props.name}
       </div>
     );
    }
 });
```

The examples that I have seen online render a jsx script embedded inside an html and a component rendered inside an html div tag but I am trying to use react.js in my node.js application. I dont want to render it inside an html tag but the component should render based on a url and should be dynamic

I have the following code snippet in my index.js file in my node application . I hit the view 'entities' through my index.js file that renders the view entities.

```
app.get('/entities', function(req, res) {
  res.render('entities', {
    title: 'Entities - Turkey Disclosure',
    name: 'Entities',
    selection: 'header-entities'
  });
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Apparently that is true for ES6 syntax only

Comment: your example works as you expect [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/39094/)

Comment: I am not using React.render. When I do, I get an error saying ReferenceError:document is not defined

Comment: How do you render your component? could you add code sample?

Comment: @The ..Please see the edit

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you're using `React.renderToString()` to render react in node application. React doesn't insert `onClick` and other event statements directly to markup. If you want to keep those events you should call `React.render()` on a node that already has server-rendered markup. React will preserve it and only attach event handlers, allowing you to have a very performant first-load experience.

[There's a nice article](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-React-render-React-renderToStaticMarkup-and-React-renderToString) explaining difference between three rendering methods in React.